# nemo: Context Menu Action Triggering a Script that Forces the Selected Symbolic Link to be Relative

Tags: bash, shell-script, symlink, nemo

My goal is to be able to right-click a symbolic link in `nemo`, triggering a custom script that forces the link to be re-written as a relative path, should it happen to possess an absolute path upon the act.

The problem is that `DRAG+SHIFT+CTRL` is hard-coded within `nemo` to to produce an absolutely-pathed symlink. This causes problems when I attempt to access the file system remotely.

My problem is I would like to retain the `DRAG+SHIFT+CTRL` gesture, I would not like to build `nemo` from source, and I would like to be able to browse any number of irrelevantly-linked directories remotely.

My proposed solution is to create a new context-menu option within `nemo` that will allow me to "fix" any one of these links by triggering a script.

I've successfully created the context-menu option by creating a new `.nemo_action` file using [the template at GitHub](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action).

There are two directories for these types of files:

- `/usr/share/nemo/actions/` for system-wide actions
- `$HOME/.local/share/nemo/actions/` for user actions

my `fix-link.nemo_action` file is as follows:

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Force Relative Link
Comment=If the file is a link to an absolute path, it will be forced to become relative.
Exec=<fix-link.sh %F>
Selection=any
Extensions=nodirs;
EscapeSpaces=true
```

and my `fix-link.sh` file (in the same directory) is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
$(ln "-rs" $(readlink -f "$1") "$1.tmp")
mv -f "$1.tmp" $(readlink -f "$1")
exit 0
```

My temporary file is being created just fine, but it refuses to overwrite the filepath returned by `$(readlink -f "$1")`. I think it might have something to do with permissions set by `nemo` when I'm initially  `DRAG+SHIFT+CTRLl`ing to create the absolutely-pathed link.

**EDIT**

@Gilles fixed the many errors in my script, at which time I discovered that I also needed to change the `Extensions=nodirs;` line in the `fix-link.nemo_action` file to read `Extensions=any;`, otherwise I wouldn't ever be able to activate this script through the context menu on even a link to a directory, which was the whole purpose for this thing.

**SO NOW**

`fix-link.nemo_action` is as follows:

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Force Relative Link
Comment=If the file is a link to an absolute path, it will be forced to become relative.
Exec=<fix-link.sh %F>
Selection=any
Extensions=any;
EscapeSpaces=true
```

and my `fix-link.sh` file is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ln -rs -- "$(readlink -f -- "$1")" "$1.tmp"
mv -f -- "$1.tmp" "$1"
```

and all is right in the world.
Thanks everybody.

Comment: `rn` used to be a Usenet reader -- did you mean `mv` instead?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your script.

- [Missing double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) around `$(readlink …)`. That will break if the link target contains whitespace or wildcard characters.
- You're using a command substitution around the `ln` command, and using the result as a command to run. Fortunately this does no harm since `ln` produces no output.
- Your `mv` command moves the symbolic link to the target location, which makes no sense.

I think this is what you meant to write:

```
#!/bin/sh
ln -rs -- "$(readlink -f -- "$1")" "$1.tmp"
mv -f -- "$1.tmp" "$1"
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`symlinks`](https://github.com/brandt/symlinks) utility (originally by Mark Lords, now maintained by J. Brandt Buckley), present in many Linux distributions.
The command `symlinks -c /path/to/directory` converts all symbolic links in the specified directory to relative links.

Comment: You are correct! That is exactly the script I was trying to write.

Comment: sadly, even though my _question_ has been answered, the slightly greater goal has not been met. see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222055/97025)