# Symlinks to directories not rendering properly through Samba

Tags: samba, symlink

I maintain many projects at a time, and keep them all organized within a single directory, `Projects`.

Now, keeping myself somewhat oriented necessitates the use of symlinks so as to associate useful pools of data amongst hundreds of deliberately placed categories (directories) and sub-categories in a cognitively analogous way. Well, my cognitive anyway.

When exploring these folders through a Samba client, any browsing session quickly devolves from a symphonic experience of harmonious symlinks to a rocky pilgrimage of dead ends and brick walls. I can't browse them. They don't render. I get errors, what the hell. So,

I was trying to achieve a particular workaround involving the discernment between absolute and relative symbolic links when I realized that I had jumped the gun: I wanted to change my (absolute by default) Cinnamon GUI (DRAG+SHIFT+CTRL+DROP) symlinks to contain relative paths when in reality it didn't matter at all when explored through a Samba client. hah.

To re-iterate, when I use a Samba client to browse through to a symlink (pathed to a directory [either relatively or absolutely]) I am unable to explore the directory structure any further, or 'inside' the symlink. The expected behavior would be for the child filetree to be grafted in with the symlink acting as the root -- happening transparently through the Samba client as if there was no symlink at all but just one continuous file structure, even if it is infinitely continuous (and happens to be stored on an NTFS partition) **just as** I observe nemo on my Cinnamon-flavored Linux Mint behaving.

So where am I wrong here? I just want to play with the file system like it was putty.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137192/97025) thanks to @Mahesh

> Edit smb.conf
>
> ```
> [global]
> unix extensions = no
>
> [share]
> follow symlinks = yes
> wide links = yes
> ```

this file happens to be found in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.